# Detecting intersecting SCNGeometries and returning it as an array

Tags: scenekit

I am trying to find a way to detect whether or not an `SCNGeometry` is intersecting with any other `SCNGeometries`. I can't seem to find anything in apple docs to support this notion, nor anything online either.

As of right now, the only method I can think of doing is enabling the Physics Engine and doing contact tests, but I want to try and avoid it if possible.

Basically, all I want to do is throw an `SCNGeometry` onto the a scene, and detect what `SCNGeometry` it is touching (Basically getting an array of geometries) so that I may process further steps.

There is no code as of yet,  I am trying to research how if possible it can be done.

I can also accept code in any programming language, so feel free to provide an answer in what you feel most comfortable with.